# Counting and Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Can the following summation be reduced to any single formula? I tried using a few combinatorial laws such as Pascal's but nothing seems to work.

$$2\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-r}k\binom{k-1}r.$$

Comment: Is $k-1 \geq n-k$?

Comment: Might or might not be. If r becomes greater than k-1,then all those terms will be 0.